# Hibernate design for entity relationship based on dynamic value

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, architecture

I need architecture design advice on the following.

I have a class named as "Order" which has following fields "orderid","ordertypeid","typeid", "price", etc.

I have three different product types for example, "cloths", "toys", and "furniture". The reason I have three different entities is they have different fields so I cannot really create one entity called as product and add those entries in it. I need to have those entities separate out so I manage their individual fields.

The problem is, when I create order record, I need to pass which type is purchased, like clothid, toyid or furnitureid.So, I created ordertypeid (this will tell me if its cloth, toy or furniture) and then typeid (which is actual id).

But how can I design this so when I fetch Order from my Spring service then it will give me record for that particular type. For example, if there is a following record in the DB,

**Order table:** 
"orderid","ordertypeid","typeid", "price"
 1       , 1        , 1        , $10

**Order type table:** 
"ordertypeid", "ordertype" 
1     , Cloth
2     , Toy
3     , Furniture

so when I fetch order, I should get the following JSON,

{

"order": {
    "cloth": {"1", "shirt","green"},
    "price": "$10"
  }
}

I know the JSON format is not valid but this is just so you get an idea.

I agree the question I asked is not correct but I cant think of the right way to structure the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance). Each product class extends abstract Product.

Use [a standard order model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831). An Order hasMany OrderItems, each of which belongsTo a Product.

Using Jackson, you can [configure it](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) to return the type of the object.